# how to resize live video in python cv2 using .set()?

Tags: python, opencv

I am learning opencv with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXlwWbU8l2o&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org this tutorial and I arrived at part 3 (resizing and rescaling). Towards the end he creates this function which should be better for live video. The function doesn't return anything and he doesn't show how it works. The funtion is `change_res(width, height)` and I think it should be called in the `while` loop for `frame_resized`.

```
import cv2 as cv


def rescale_frame(frame, scale):    # works for image, video, live video
    width = int(frame.shape[1] * scale)
    height = int(frame.shape[0] * scale)
    dimensions = (width, height)
    return cv.resize(frame, dimensions, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)


def change_res(width, height):      # works only for live video
    capture.set(3, width)
    capture.set(4, height)


capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)    # integer to capture from webcam, path to capture video file

while True:
    isTrue, frame = capture.read()
    frame_resized = rescale_frame(frame, scale=.2)    # this line
    cv.imshow("Video", frame)
    cv.imshow("Video Resized", frame_resized)
    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord("q"):       # press "q" key to exit loop
        break


capture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What exactly hinders you to put the call to whereever you think is prudent and see if it works?  How about only using it once before the while loop and see if the capturingformat is somehow changed? Why ask here? What is the problem?

Comment: `capture.set(3, width)` -- hmm, I guess typing `CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` is too much work. Honestly, any teaching resource that gives you example code with magic numbers like this is probably better avoided.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have tried with frame_resized = change_res(frame[0], frame[0])
    cv.imshow("Video Resized", frame_resized)
but it doesn't work. I don't even know what to put in the brackets, and it seems absurd to me that the function doesn't return anything

Comment: You set an option on the capture device - why should it return anything. Try `change_res(700,200)` before the while loop - this is nothing you do frame for frame, it is a setting for the capturing device....

Comment: @PatrickArtner I just tried putting frame_resized = change_res(700, 200) before the while loop and got a couple of errorss :(

Comment: You have to use a frame size that the camera supports. 700x200 is unlikely to be one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dan Mašek 's comment I managed to understand.
The `.set()` method changes the resolution of the camera, it doesnt need to be in the `while` loop because `capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)` keeps going by defeault forever unless `capture.release()` is called.

```
import cv2 as cv


def rescale_frame(frame, scale):    # works for image, video, live video
    width = int(frame.shape[1] * scale)
    height = int(frame.shape[0] * scale)
    dimensions = (width, height)
    return cv.resize(frame, dimensions, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)


capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)  # integer to capture from webcam, path to capture video file
capture.set(3, 1440)

while True:
    isTrue, frame = capture.read()
    frame_resized = rescale_frame(frame, scale=.2)
    cv.imshow("video with set", frame)
    cv.imshow("Video Resized", frame_resized)
    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord("q"):       # press "q" key to exit loop
        break


capture.release()   # stop capturing the image/video
cv.destroyAllWindows()      # close windows
```

So, I wanted a small and a big window showing what the webcam was capturing. Currently this code captures the video, makes it 2560x1440 (with `.set`) which is enormous and then it takes those frames and rescales them with the `rescale_frame` function to make it smaller.
I found out that this `.set()` method is more efficient for a single video but if I want two I should show as small the default one and then use `rescale_frame` to make it bigger.